# Load different contents in HTML when selecting different options in drop-down list

Tags: html, xml, dom

I'm going to build a web UI for a system originally using command lines. People will use this web UI to select options from drop-down lists and submit their requirements.

Here's a feature I would like to implement: options are stored in XML files, when people select a top-level option in the drop-down list, the web page could load automatically the contents in a corresponding XML file, and display the sub-level options contained in this file.

I'm new to HTML and XML, after some research I think it may be related to XML and DOM but I'm not sure. Could you please give some examples or tutorials of this feature?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jquery's AJAX and GET - Method is very useful for things like this: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

With these, you can make a specific query to a specific file on a server. Via a parameter, you can specify, which item you want to have as a response.

```
$.get("backend.php", { item: "1" }) //Pull menu item 1 from server
.done(function(data) {

$("#menuitem").html(data); //Place Data in html menu here

});
```

It is common to transmit the data in the JSON - Format to the server, with json encode you can do this with PHP:

http://php.net/manual/de/function.json-encode.php